# Implicit conversion from Nullable to normal, any ideas?

Tags: c#, nullable, implicit-conversion

I want some idea to how implicitly convert nullable "?" variables to district ones.

given this example

```
int? x = 5;

int y = x; //this gonna fail, !!!
```

i need some way to override = parameter, but unfortunately the = parameter is not overloadable... any suggestions

I'm using C#

Comment: What language is this in? Or is this language-agnostic and I fail to notice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to implement an [implicit cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=VS.100).aspx), but only to or from types you define.  For example, doing something like this..

```
public class NullableExtensions 
{
    public static implicit operator int(int? value)
    {
        return value ?? default(int);
    }
}
```

.. will return a [CS0556](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x7fay24(v=VS.90).aspx) compile error because the cast doesn't include the user-defined type.

The closest you could do is define your own Nullable type that does contain an implicit cast operator:

```
public struct ImplicitNullable<T> where T: struct
{
    public bool HasValue { get { return this._value.HasValue; } }
    public T Value { get { return this._value.Value; } }

    public ImplicitNullable(T value) : this() { this._value = value; }
    public ImplicitNullable(Nullable<T> value) : this() { this._value = value; }

    public static implicit operator ImplicitNullable<T>(T value) { return new ImplicitNullable<T>(value); }
    public static implicit operator ImplicitNullable<T>(Nullable<T> value) { return new ImplicitNullable<T>(value); }

    public static implicit operator T(ImplicitNullable<T> value) { return value._value ?? default(T); }
    public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(ImplicitNullable<T> value) { return value._value; }

    private Nullable<T> _value { get; set; }

    // Should define other Nullable<T> members, especially 
    // Equals and GetHashCode to avoid boxing
}
```

Note that although it's possible to write this code, it will likely lead to hard to trace bugs.  I would recommend using an explicit cast, or throwing an exception when the value is `null`.

Afterwards, you can cast to and from as expected:

```
static void Main()
{
    int myInt = 1;
    int? nullableInt = 2;

    ImplicitNullable<int> implicitInt;

    // Convert from int or int?
    implicitInt = myInt;
    implicitInt = nullableInt;

    // Convert to int or int?
    myInt = implicitInt;
    nullableInt = implicitInt;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You have two options, access the value directly (if you know for sure it's not null):

```
int y = x.Value;
```

or, use the null coalescing operator:

```
int y = x ?? 0; // 0 if null...
```

Comment: well yes, that's right, but i need it to be done implicitly, cuz there are lots of code using it.

Comment: @Mustafa - if you figure out how to do that implicity, let me know ;)  In C# you can't overload the assignment operator. You also can't extend `int`. How you solve this will depend on your application's architecture. Can you go the other way and replace all `int`s with `int?`s since `int` will implicitly convert to `int?`?

Comment: @Mustafa: You can't override the '=' operator, it's not a method. If you were comparing values using a `.Equals` method, then you could've written an override for it.

Comment: you're right, i cannot extend 'int' and cannot overload the = operator, I think, i've no other choice other redesign the domain model to use the correct data types, cheers.

Comment: also int y = x.HasValue ? x.Value : 0; //0 if null

Answer (score 3):

Wait, I'm so confused...

Why don't you just use [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx)?

Comment: Cause, i've an already written code, and i don't want to hand over it typing after every prop "GetValueOrDefault()", Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I'm assuming this is C#**.

You need to either cast, or use `.value`:

```
 int? x = 5;
 int y;

 if(x.HasValue)
     y = x.Value;
 else
     throw new//... handle error or something
```